# Is it possible to split an impl into different modules?

Tags: rust

I am trying to split an `impl` into different modules.
The items in the child `impl` blocks should be accessible by the parent `impl`, but not publicly accessible by the users of the struct/enum that is implemented.

Here is my attempt:

```
mod foo {
    pub struct Foo {
        field: String
    }

    impl Foo {
        pub fn new() -> Foo {
            Foo { field: "Joe".to_string() }
        }
        pub fn pubfn(&self) {
            self.my_impl();
        }
    }

    // Ideally, this should be in a separate file
    mod foo_impl_details {
        impl super::Foo {
            // If I make this `pub`, it will be publicly visible to
            // users of `Foo`, not just the impl block in `super`
            fn my_impl(&self) {
                println!("{} reporting for duty!", self.field);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = foo::Foo::new();
    foo.pubfn();
}
```

This results in a compile error:

```
<anon>:11:13: 11:27 error: method `my_impl` is private
<anon>:11             self.my_impl();
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I mark the `my_impl` method with `pub`, it will be publicly accessible not only to the parent module's `impl` block, but also to the outside users of `foo::Foo`, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems somewhat like expected behaviour: the `my_impl` method is private and thus only visible inside the *module* in which it is declared. On the other hand, it's strange that the `pub` version is visible everywhere, despite `foo_impl_details` being a private module. I filed [#16398](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16398) about this.

You can separate modules (and thus files, since `mod foo { ... }` is the same as `mod foo;` with the code in `foo.rs` or `foo/mod.rs`) out while maintaining privacy by using freestanding functions, e.g.

```
mod foo {
    pub struct Foo {
        field: String
    }

    impl Foo {
        pub fn new() -> Foo {
            Foo { field: "Joe".to_string() }
        }
        pub fn pubfn(&self) {
            foo_impl_details::my_impl(self);
        }
    }

    mod foo_impl_details {
        fn my_impl(x: &super::Foo) {
            println!("{} reporting for duty!", x.field);
        }
    }
}
```

There's no difference between freestanding functions and methods other than the calling syntax.

Also, there are a variety of issues with writing non-trait impls not adjacent to the type declaration so this behaviour is probably not by-design, e.g.

- [#9052](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/9052)
- [#9584](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/9584)
- [#12729](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12729)

And thus there is [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/155) for (temporarily) removing this functionality.

Comment: I was thinking about using freestanding functions too. It seems like the cleanest option.

Answer (score 7):

This works.

```
mod foo {
    use self::extension::Extension;

    pub struct Foo {
        field: String
    }

    impl Foo {
        pub fn new() -> Foo {
            Foo { field: "Joe".to_string() }
        }
        pub fn pubfn(&self) {
            self.my_impl();
        }
    }

    mod extension {
        pub trait Extension {
            fn my_impl(&self);
        }
        impl Extension for super::Foo {
            fn my_impl(&self) {
                println!("{} reporting for duty!", self.field);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that the OP is old, but just for other users reference.

I believe the proper solution to be [`pub(super)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html#pubin-path-pubcrate-pubsuper-and-pubself):

```rust
mod foo {
    pub struct Foo {
        field: String
    }

    impl Foo {
        pub fn new() -> Foo {
            Foo { field: "Joe".to_string() }
        }
        pub fn pubfn(&self) {
            self.my_impl();
        }
    }

    // Ideally, this should be in a separate file
    mod foo_impl_details {
        impl super::Foo {
            pub(super) fn my_impl(&self) {
                println!("{} reporting for duty!", self.field);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = foo::Foo::new();
    foo.pubfn();
    // uncomment following line to get an error
    // foo.my_impl()
}
```

It seems to me that this has all the required features:

- makes the original code working, printing the message in `my_impl`
- `my_impl` is not accessible by `Foo` user

Answer (score 1):

Plain `impl` blocks? Well, that’s something that is at present quite buggy and although you can work around those bugs with a little difficulty it [may well be removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/155). I strongly advise not attempting to do it in the first place.

As for implementations of a trait, they can go anywhere in the crate.